# FATAL: database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

No logro dar con la solución a este problema

Comment: Agrega los detalles del problema en tu pregunta. Revisar [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso es porque efectivamente no has creado la base de datos.

Prueba ejecutando:

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```